# Try (hd0,1): NTFS5: stalls forever

Tags: bootloader

After installing Ubuntu it asks me to reboot my system, when I do that I get following error:

```
Try (hd0,0): NTFS5: No Wubildr
Try (hd0,1): NTFS5:
```

the second line just stalls forever.

*How should I proceed?*

Answer (score 1):

You've used WUBI to install Ubuntu and WUBI is deprecated.

Have a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) instead on how to install Ubuntu.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**